# MSAA/ CSAA / FXAA How to set the mode in OpenGL?

Tags: opengl, antialiasing

I'm learning OpenGL and something I am stuck with is AA. Specially when I want to turn it on and off at runtime. I know that I can set the samplecount when I create a FBO and blit it over to the final window. When I want to change the mode I switch the FBO and everything is fine. The question I am completely stuck with is, how do I change the mode and also important, how do I query the modes that the card supports. With mode I mean CSAA,MSAA,.. .I can't find a lot. At least I know that it is vendor specific. 
Hope anyone can point me in the right direction. Thanks

Comment: Old relevant question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6129797). I hope it's no longer valid, but still ..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Multisampling is a property of the framebuffer. You enable multisampling by rendering to a multisampled framebuffer while `GL_MULTISAMPLING` is enabled. If `GL_MULTISAMPLING` is not enabled when you render to a multisample framebuffer, the pixels covered by that rendering operation replicate their data across all covered samples.

To make a [framebuffer object](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Framebuffer_Object) a multisampled framebuffer, you attach multisampled images to it. They will all need to use the same sample count, and all images in the framebuffer must be multisample.

To make the [default framebuffer](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Default_Framebuffer) multisampled, you must create your context with multiple samples. This requires the use of the [WGL/GLX_ARB_multisample extension](https://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/multisample.txt), as appropriate to your platform.

Nowadays, the general pattern is to leave the default framebuffer non-multisampled and create your own multisample FBO images. Then, you [blit from your multisample FBO to the default framebuffer's back buffer](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Framebuffer#Multisampling_Considerations) to display the multisampled data.

CSAA is an NVIDIA thing, with [an extension](https://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/NV/framebuffer_multisample_coverage.txt) to govern its use.

FXAA is not a piece of hardware; it's an algorithm. Some drivers have control panel settings that back-door it in. That's generally a bad idea, since they can't tell when you're rendering the UI (something that shouldn't use the FXAA algorithm). So it's generally up to you to implement it.

Comment: I'd add to the last point, that the FXAA algorithm is available for download for both DirectX and OpenGL from the Nvidia developer who made it.

Answer (score 1):

FXAA doesn't come with OpenGL implementations, you have to find and use a shader that implements it.

CSAA can be used on NVIDIA GPUs using `GL_NV_framebuffer_multisample_coverage`.

Comment: OP also asked about MSAA, which must set when conxtext is created. There are special functions to enable MSAA in libraries (like SDL or GLFW) that can create contexts.