# How do I enable FSAA in OpenTK?

Tags: opentk, antialiasing

All I could find about it is [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23048723/how-to-achieve-better-anti-aliasing-in-glcontrol-in-opentk), but `GraphicsMode` alone doesn't enable anti-aliasing:

```
using System.Drawing;
using OpenTK;
using OpenTK.Graphics;
using OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        using (var window = new GameWindow(800, 60, new GraphicsMode(32, 24, 0, 8)))
        {
            window.Resize += (sender, e) => { GL.Viewport(window.Size); };
            window.RenderFrame += (sender, e) =>
            {
                GL.Clear(ClearBufferMask.ColorBufferBit);
                GL.Color3(Color.Red);
                GL.Begin(PrimitiveType.Triangles);
                GL.Vertex2(-1, 1);
                GL.Vertex2(-1, 0);
                GL.Vertex2(1, 0);
                GL.End();
                window.SwapBuffers();
            };
            window.Run();
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MSAA/ CSAA / FXAA How to set the mode in OpenGL?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/112325/msaa-csaa-fxaa-how-to-set-the-mode-in-opengl)

Comment: @Rabbid76, I think it should be much simpler in OpenTK.

Comment: Maybe it should, but it isn't.

Comment: @Rabbid76, then what's the point in this `GraphicsMode` constructor with `int samples`? Is there any documentation for this?

Answer (score 1):

It's in the constructor of `GraphicsMode`:

`new GameWindow(1280, 800, 
    new GraphicsMode(new ColorFormat(8, 8, 8, 0), 
      24, // Depth bits
      8,  // Stencil bits
      4   // FSAA samples
    ), 
"Title");`

Comment: Did I use it wrongly?

Comment: Your code actually produces MSAA on my machine. I wonder why it doesn't work for you.

Comment: Wow, thanks. What OS and video card, and whether .NET or Mono?

Comment: Win7 64, .net,  AMD hd6970 (mid range dedicated GPU from 5 years ago)